# Specify origin of Math.atan2

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, geometry, atan2

`Math.atan2()` is a very useful function for calculating angles. However, I cannot wrap my head around one thing:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
    r = Math.atan2(event.pageY, event.pageX);
    deg = r * 180/Math.PI;
    console.log(deg);   
})
```

console.log indicates that 0,0 from where the angle is being calculated is at the upper left corner of the screen. How would I go about calculating the angle from a different origin, say the centre of the screen?

Comment: Why did someone down vote this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would subtract the coordinates of your origin from the coordinates that you want to find the angle of:

```
r = Math.atan2(event.pageY - originY, event.pageX - originX);
```